# in_irq() returns false while being called from arm interrupt handler

Tags: linux, kernel, interrupt-handling

Both in_irq() and in_interrupt() return false while being called from gic_handle_irq which is at the very beginning of ARM interrupt handler.
What is wrong and how to avoid it?